# Making a css transition slide over top of another container

Tags: css

Is it possible to make a css transition that causes the width of one div to expand slide over another div instead of moving it out of the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, here are the HTML and the CSS

HTML:

```
<body>

  <div class="overlord"></div>
  <div class="target"></div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```css
.target
{
  z-index:-1;
  position:fixed;
  left:120px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
}

div.overlord
{
  float:left;
  z-index:999;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  transition:width 2s;
  -webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari */
}

div.overlord:hover
{
  z-index:999;
  width:300px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UGmA2/)

Comment: I would like to actually understand what I'm doing can you just explain what the z-index part is doing?

Comment: The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. At that script above we set the order of target div to be below of other element. here is the [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: take a look at the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UGmA2/) link, at the bottom of my answer

Comment: I think the problem is I'm having trouble setting the position to fixed. The problem is it is inside another div tag that is centered in the page. So there isnt always a fixed distance from the left side

Comment: That is definately the problem I got it to work but the rest of the page didn't work right because I cant find a way to fix the distance to something that will always be the same difference away.

Comment: provide me the fiddle then, we'll see how can we help

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UGmA2/2/ the .main class selector position should be relative, update: set the .sidebar position into absolute, then it will be like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/UGmA2/3/)